# Adding Multiple spelling dictionaries in Texmaker

Tags: texmaker, spelling

I am trying to write a bilingual text in Texmaker. For this I would like the spell check to recognise both languages, yet in the Texmaker preferences (Options → Configure Texmaker → Editor → Spelling Dictionary) I can only choose one .dic file.

Is it possible to choose multiple files here or will I have to join the two into one file. If so what would be the fastest way to achieve that?